# Got an error when trying to install bagisto / laravel-aliexpress-dropship

Tags: laravel, composer-php

tried installing bagisto
/
laravel-aliexpress-dropship
but got

bagisto/aliexpress-dropship dev-master requires symfony/dom-crawler ^5.3 -> found symfony/dom-crawler[v5.3.0-BETA1, ..., 5.4.x-dev] but the package is fixed to v5.2.4 (lock file version) by a partial update and that version does not match. Make sure you list it as an argument for the update command.

bagisto
/
laravel-aliexpress-dropship is a composer package for laravel application

pls can anyone help me resolve this, i really would appreciate your time and effort

Comment: composer require bagisto / laravel-aliexpress-dropship -W

Answer (score 0):

`bagisto/aliexpress-dropship` is so new that it requires parts of Symfony 5.3. Currently, you have installed `symfony/dom-crawler` from Symfony 5.2.

Using `composer require bagisto/aliexpress-dropship -W` could help to resolve this, as it would also update that Symfony package - if allowed by the other version constraints. If they block the installation, you need to check why this happens through `composer why-not symfony/dom-crawler 5.3.4`